# vue router $this not defined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am using vue-router, in one of the component/vue, I tried to load histories transaction from database when the specific component is load:

```
<script>
import store from '../store'
export default { 
    data() {
        return {
            histories: []
        }
    },
    route: {
        activate() {
            $this.getHistories()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getHistories() {
            $this.histories = store.getHistories()
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I got these 2 errors:

```
build.js:12642 [vue-router] Uncaught error during transition:
build.js:28551 Uncaught ReferenceError: $this is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this` doesn't exist, you need to use `this`:

```
export default { 
    data() {
        return {
            histories: []
        }
    },
    route: {
        activate() {
            this.getHistories()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getHistories() {
            this.histories = store.getHistories()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone comming here from search looking for an answer for Vue Router 4.x check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65284532/268125