# How to get params of router in Vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I created a project in Vue.js 3 and TypeScript.

router.js

```
{
  path: "/app/:id",
  name: "Detail",
  component: Detail,
  props: true
},
```

App.js

```html
<script lang="ts">

...

onMounted(() => {
  const id = $route.params.id;
    ...
});
```

But this results in an error:

> "Cannot find name '$route'."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use this.$route

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Vue Router 4.x provides [`useRoute()`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#useRoute) for that:

```js
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default {
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()

    onMounted(() => {
      const id = route.params.id
    })
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/getting-current-route-wcomposition-api-in-vue-router-4-e6wlw?file=/src/App.vue:370-400)

Comment: ~"Property 'params' does not exist on type 'Router'.ts(2339)"~ -> Update: Never mind, useRoute without the r at the end... *facepalm*

Comment: make sure there are "useRoute" and "useRouter"

Answer (score 39):

If we are using the newest Vue 3 'script setup' SFC way, then

```
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const route = useRoute();  
const id = route.params.id; // read parameter id (it is reactive) 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the composition api to write your own composition that offers nicer syntax and gracefully handles when param is array.

```
const id = useRouteParam('id')
```

composition

```
import { computed, Ref } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export function useRouteParam(param: string, useFirstIfArray?: true): Ref<string>
export function useRouteParam(param: string, useFirstIfArray: false): Ref<string | string[]>
export function useRouteParam(param: string, useFirstIfArray = true): Ref<string | string[]> {
  const route = useRoute()

  return computed(() => {
    let paramValue = route.params[param]

    if (useFirstIfArray && Array.isArray(paramValue) && paramValue.length) {
      [paramValue] = paramValue
    }

    return paramValue
  })
}
```

https://github.com/PrefectHQ/vue-compositions/tree/main/src/useRouteParam

Answer (score 0):

I used this to get query data code:

`this.$router.currentRoute._value.query`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).